# com.google.android.gms version mismatch

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting below build 
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.3.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

my build.gradle is below

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3"
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1"
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'


compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.5'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:+') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
}


compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
compile 'com.github.silvestrpredko:dot-progress-bar:1.1'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
```

Answer (score 1):

apply this plugIn

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: you using different version numbers. make sure all are same version

Comment: what about version numbers you using different  versions 16.0.3 and 16.0.1

Comment: configurations.all() {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.0"
}
   }

Comment: do you add firebase json file

Answer (score 1):

There were no apply from Google Services in your `build.gradle` so add:

```
Apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And also:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

In the other `Build.gradle` and then it should work.

Comment: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' . solved my issue.         
Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it. There are also [samples](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android) in here, you can use them.